# How to center movie player programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I need movie player to be centered vertically.

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: ???, y: self.view.frame.size.height/4, width: 200, height: 200)
```

I've tried `self.view.frame.size.width/2` and `self.view.center.x`.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `center` property after setting frame.

```
moviePlayer.view.center = self.view.center;
```

One more to consider - if `moviePlayer.view` is a subview of `self.view`, don't use `self.view.frame`. Consider using `self.view.bounds` instead.

To center vertically

```
CGPoint center = self.view.center;
center.y = //whatever you need
moviePlayer.view.center = center;
```

**Update**

As @Antonio mentioned, it works only if self.view's top left corner is screen left top corner itself.

Better way

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), <#Whatever you need#>);
moviePlayer.view.center = center;
```

But still, I suggest using NSLayoutConstraints for greater good =)

**Something to consider**

However, setting frames that way isn't the best - you will be forced to calculate each view's position and size manualy. If your layout is plain, use `autoresizingMask` and `contentMode`. Like that

```
//after setting moviePlayer.view.frame
moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
self.view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

In case, your content isn't simple enough, use `NSLayoutConstraint`s. Also, using it you can center only by one axis (vertically or horizontally)

Comment: Thank you, works fine, but is there some way i can center it only vertically ?

Comment: `moviePlayer.view.center = self.view.center;` probably won't work here. The `center` property is the position of the view's center in it's super view's coordinate system and since `self.view` is the super view in this case, `self.view.center` will only be correct if `self.view`'s upper left corner is in the upper left corner of the window. If you replace it with `CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds))` instead, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two programming idioms that you can use for centering a subview within it's super view. If you are writing a custom view, this code should go in that view's `layoutSubviews` method. If this is part of a view controller, it should go in its `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

**Method 1: Setting the `center`**

```
CGFloat x = CGRectGetMidX(superview.bounds);
CGFloat y = CGRectGetMidY(superview.bounds);
subview.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

**Method 2: Setting the `frame`**

```
CGFloat width = (... calculate subview width ...);
CGFloat height = (... calculate subview height ...);
CGFloat x = (CGRectGetWidth(superview.bounds) - width) / 2.0;
CGFloat y = (CGRectGetWidth(superview.bounds) - height) / 2.0;
subview.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```